# Is there any way to make my function return a dynamic array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, dynamic, return

So at the moment I have a function I made returning a static array, is there any way to make it return a dynamic array for the sake of efficiency?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int *charpos(char *str, char ch)
{
    int *bff, bc, ec, i, strln;
    static int ret[255];
    bc = 0;
    ec = 0;

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;

    strln = i;
    for(i = 0; i <= strln; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ch)
            ec++;
    }

    bff = malloc(sizeof(int)*ec);
    if(sizeof(bff) > sizeof(ret))
    {
        free(bff);
        return 0;
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= 255; i++) ret[i] = '\0';
    for(i = 0; i <= strln; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == ch)
        {
            ret[bc] = i;
            bc++;
        }
    }

    free(bff);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Putting aside what can be returned from a function, is there such a thing as a dynamic array in C? Did you mean pointer, instead? Arrays are not pointers. http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/

Comment: "Dynamic array" implies dynamic memory allocation, which is most often considerably less efficient than non-dynamic (static or automatic) memory allocation. So, what "efficiency" are you talking about?

Comment: Presumably memory efficiency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions cannot return arrays, period.  You can of course a pointer or take a pointer to a block of memory that has been allocated by the caller.  So, in your case...

```
int *ret = malloc(255 * sizeof int);  // caller must deallocate!
```

This does change the semantics of your code however.  The caller of your function is now responsible for calling `free()` on the returned pointer.  If they do not you will leak memory, so this adds some amount of complexity that did not exist before.  I would prefer something like this instead:

```
void charpos(int *p, size_t size, const char *str, char ch) {
    // initialize the memory 
    memset(p, 0, size * sizeof int);
    
    // your other code here...

    size_t len = strlen(str);
    // fill the caller's memory
    for(i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if(str[i] == ch)
            p[bc++] = i;
    }
}
```

You're returning a pointer to `int` which referes to the first element of a statically allocated array.

Comment: You can do some jiggery pokery with returning a structure that contains an array, but +1 for the sane answer.

Comment: @CarlNorum: That's true, you could.  I'm not sure what more the OP expects from an answer on this though.

Comment: No I didn't down vote it I'm sorry this is my first time posting here I have been teaching myself C via a book my friend found in the garbage, and just needed some help so I registered here.

Comment: @KeithMiller: No problem, I wish I had an explanation for the downvote though... well, regardless, you can't dynamically allocate an *array* (pointers and arrays are not the same thing!) but you can certainly allocate a block of memory dynamically and return a pointer to it.

Comment: @Ed, I downvoted it because your answer initially only had the first two sentences, which weren't very helpful on their own. I took it back once you edited your post. Didn't mean to cause so much puzzlement!

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Ah, ok.  Can't really blame you for downvoting a terse/incomplete answer as I do it all the time and then argue with those who complain about why they shouldn't be posting incomplete answers in the first place :D

Comment: *"...you're returning a pointer to int which referes to the first element of a statically allocated array."* I'm guessing this is a novice mistake to make the `returning a temporary` error go away. Good advice on the `free` though. I would definitely pass a pointer to the function instead, so that no dynamic allocation is required at all.

Comment: @EdS.

re: "dynamically allocating an array"

I've always understood the phrase to implicitly mean "allocating a block of memory where we'll store an array". I agree that pointers and arrays are not the same thing, but the phrase itself (at least the way I interpreted it) never said they were. The "array" in this case is the block of memory you've just allocated, not the pointer to it.

Comment: @DennisMeng: But you aren't allocating an array; you are allocating a blob of memory and getting a pointer to it.  The word "array" has meaning, it is a true type, it is not simply a blob of memory.  Yes, they are typically used interchangeably, but that doesn't make it correct, and for beginners it is really nice to know that arrays and pointers are not at all the same thing.

Comment: Again, we're not saying that arrays and pointers are the same thing. When we're using the phrase, we're allocating a blob for "an array of objects." We're talking about the data structure, not the data type.

Comment: @DennisMeng: When posed the question "how to return an array from a function?" by a beginner who is actually allocating a static array and returning it (a pointer to it, but does he know that?) then I think it is appropriate to be technically correct. I don't disagree with you about usage, but I assume nothing when speaking to a beginner, that's all.

Comment: All I was saying is that there's nothing wrong with the phrase itself. I'll agree however, that the OP is confused about the finer points and needs some coaching.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Agreed. If it were you and I talking about this I don't think either of us would be confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually allocate more space then you need with static int and not have to worry about dynamics. Here is how I solved it:

```
//indefinite reads, actually only up to 20
int * readDataAD7142(int addr, int numRegs){
  static int data[20];
  int i = 0;

  //Do something with this data array. Something that requires less then 20 elements

  return data;  
}
```

Here is the code that calls it

```
 int *p;
 int i;
 p = readDataAD7142(0x0000, 6);

 for(i=0; i<6; i++){
  Serial.println(p[i], HEX);
 }
```

Perfect and easy if you have more memory then you need and little time (you need to be a bit lazy too).